# Creating a proxy delegate using reflection for any event

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, .net-4.5

I am trying to write a library that allows the attaching of events using attributes, and I want to create a set of convenience method signatures.

For example, a button will have a `Click` event with a handler signature of `void(object, EventArgs)`.

I have already mapped the methods that match this signature directly:

```
// the object that raises the event
Object eventSource = ...;
EventInfo evnt = ...; 

// the object with the target method
Object target = ...;
MethodInfo method = ...;

// create and attach delegate
var del Delegate.CreateDelegate(evnt.EventHandlerType, target, method);
evnt.AddEventHandler(eventSource, del);
```

This works well as long as the methods are the same/compatible, even when detaching an event:

```
evnt.RemoveEventHandler(eventSource, del);
```

However, I would like to also be able to map parameterless methods.
Is it possible to create a delegate that will accept any arguments, but then ignore them, and invoke a desired method on an object?

For an example, in the working bit, I can do:

```
// the method
void MyClickMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

// the execution
var evnt = myButton.GetType().GetEvent("Click");
var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("MyClickMethod")
AttachEvent(/*eventSource*/ myButton, /*evnt*/ evnt, /*target*/ this, /*method*/ method);
```

But, I would also like to be able to attach this method:

```
void MyClickMethod()
{
}
```

My logic here is that we can attach any parameterless method on any type to any event. This is often very helpful. It is important that I be able to detach any events.

What goes on in my mind, would to somehow create a delegate that does this:

```
eventSource.Event += (sender, e) => {
    target.method();
};
```

Is there a way to do this cleanly?

Comment: Those delegates/events will not be compatible types. What you can do here for future convenient usage is predefine your signatures as _generics_ with say 0 to up to 10 parameters, similarly as Action<T>, Action<T1, T2>... and Func<TR>, Func<T, TR> etc

Comment: I don't control either end. I am writing a library for the middle. Some framework (eg: .NET) defines the events and another (some app) provides the methods. I just create a set of attributes that will be used to hook it all up...